# Reinstall Windows 7 on dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot, system-restore

I've just upgraded to Windows 8 from 7, but one of my programs doesn't work. (The required drivers don't work under Windows 8.)

This program is imperative. So I need to reinstall 7 with 8, as a dual boot.

I've got a full system backup (The default Microsoft 'WindowsImageBackup'). How can I restore the system **from this backup?**

(Note: Win8 is on C:, so Win7 will have to be on D:)

Comment: If I were you I'd try backing up the win8 partition, then doing a clean install of win7 on D:\ and restoring the backup directly from win7.

Comment: Restoring the system would depend on how you made the backup, i.e. the tools you used to create it. As for the dual boot, you can install whichever you want first, you'll see them both in the boot menu. If you install Windows 8 first and want to use the graphical boot menu execute in an elevated command prompt in Windows 8 `bcdboot L:\Windows` where `L` is the letter where it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this:

You use "Create a System Repair Disk" in control panel. Kinda obvious what it does.

Answer (score 0):

To dual boot, you'll first need to allocate disk space - either by dividng the existing disk into two partitions or adding a new drive. Then restore windows 7 to the new partition/drive. Then Boot Windows 8, and modify the Boot manager to present the windows 7 partition as an option. You may have to re-install the Windows 7 boot software depending on your configuration. [Here's one person's experience](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/0fc8d173-c63c-4430-86d0-924f8411c973).

Something that you may want to try - depending on if the device is accessible thru USB - is to run Window 7 as a virtual system (VirtualBox with Guest extensions to access the host USB).

Comment: It seems I haven't been too clear. I know about partitions, I know about boot managing, but I need to reinstall the system **from this backup**.

Comment: Which backup software are you using? Ghost, Acronis, Microsoft,...? What problems are you having using the particular restore function of that utility on your new setup? Isn't the restore to the new parition working ok? Or are you asking about how to configure the restored partition. You should probably answer by editing your original answer. good luck.

Comment: Sorry, should have said. The default Microsoft 'WindowsImageBackup'

Comment: So the question is how the restore process works for MS Backup: You can boot up from a windows 7 install disk, and pick the restore options (eventually pointing to the new partition). Here's the steps from microsoft: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Restore-your-computer-from-a-system-image-backup (Link is for vista, but same for windows 7)